# How to add my table in database and save the table?

Tags: magento-1.8

I am new to magento.I had created the table with the button "save Form" in form.phtml.I am unable to save the table data to database.Please help me.

Comment: Are you doing it for front or admin?

Comment: I am doing for front.There is no action performing when I click on the button.

Comment: you have to call your custom action. So you will need to create a module for this. Check this http://inchoo.net/magento/creating-an-eav-based-models-in-magento/

Comment: How I need to create a module and call the custom action.Can you please help me.

Comment: http://inchoo.net/magento/creating-an-eav-based-models-in-magento/

Comment: How I need to change these valuse according to my form.Please suggest me.                                                                                                                       $post->setTitle('Test title');
        $post->setAuthor('Zoran Šalamun');

Comment: you can simply ad a new module with a controller and call the controller action via jquery post method.If you are still in a need i can show you the way.

Comment: I want still.Please show me in detail